# Object to Map conversion

Tags: java, object, dictionary, collections, key-value

I have a Map of Maps like below in a configuration file

```
<Map>
      <entry key="C3239">
        <value>
          <Map>
            <entry key="enddate" value="08/12/2015"/>
            <entry key="reason" value="test"/>
          </Map>
        </value>
      </entry>
      <entry key="CAD0139">
        <value>
          <Map>
            <entry key="enddate" value="08/12/2015"/>
            <entry key="reason" value="test 12345"/>
          </Map>
        </value>
      </entry>
    </Map>
```

i am checking whether entry key(Id =CAD0139) is exist or not .

```
Config.containsKey(Id);
```

if the key exists i can get the key, value pair like this 
`Object obj = Config.get(Id);` // this returns a object with below key value pair

so now my question is how can i convert an object to Map and retrieve the values of enddate and reason.

Can someone please suggest some easy way to achieve this.

Thanks.

Comment: Load this config as `Map<String, Map<String, String>>`.

Comment: Look at javax.xml.transform package: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/transform/package-frame.html

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question, the simplest solution is to cast the result into a map:

`Map value = (Map)Config.get(Id)`

I'd recommend making the Map strongly typed, if possible, e.g.

```
Map<String,Map<String,String>> Config = new HashMap<>();
// then later
if( Config.containsKey(Id)) {
  Map<String,String> value = Config.get(Id);
}
```